# How to handle error and validation messages in cypress js

Tags: javascript, error-handling, cypress, alerts

This is not visible in DOM. I cannot capture it

[image]

I tried window, stub but not able to get the class and the text.
please reply I need to apply this immediately
I need to validate the text messages which devs has created with a library

Comment: If it is not in the DOM how does is it visible there?